# Transparent Button Flashes White on Page Load

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a button with a transparent bg.  On hover it changes to some color.
And a transition is set to smooth it out.  Lets say the page visible behind it is red (anything other than white).

```
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
  transition: background-color 0.5s
  &:hover: {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
  }
```

Problem: on page load, or more precisely element load (using React), the button will go from white to transparent.

How to fix?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sounds like it's picking up the `transition` on load but not the `background-color`. try explicitly adding the style to the element; if that fixes it then look for other rules that are being picked up for the element